# using custom types in a WCF service

Tags: wcf

I'm new in WCF and now stuck in something about using custom types in WCF service.

I have two classes Class1 and Class2 in TestClass project

```
public Class1: ArrayList{
    public string street;
}

public Class2{
    public string name;
    public string address;
}
```

My WCF service TestService include function DoSomething using two above classes

```
public string DoSomething(Class1 c1){
     return c1.street; 
}
```

And when try to call this function

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
c1.Add(c2);
ServiceClient1.Dosomething(c1);
```

I get the Exception

```
There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:c1. The 
InnerException message was 'Type 'WebApplication1.Class2' with data contract name 
'Class2:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication1' is not expected. Add 
any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the  
KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to  
DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Can anyone tell me how to add DataContract for a class defined outside the WCF service, and how to solve this problem. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Add the lines below to your service interface declaration (add them just below the ServiceContract attribute):

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Class1))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Class2))]
```

alternatively, and this is the recommended approach, define your set of DTO objects exported by the service and decorate them with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Oliver Weichhold but I try your suggestion and still get the same exception. I'm trying define a DTO object but is there any way to solve it directly?